# Codeigniter Tank_auth library | How to protect controllers and show login page if user not logged in

Tags: codeigniter, authentication, controller

I have successfully implemented the Tank Auth library to my CodeIgniter project and would now like to protect my 'members' controller.

How can I stop users that have not registered and logged in viewing my members pages?

If there a default function in tank_auth to do so? If not how should I go about doing so?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add this to the __construct function of your controller

```
if(!$this->tank_auth->is_logged_in())
{
    redirect('/auth/login');
}
```